# Why does my code complain about marshalled interface in VS2017 but not in VS2013 when intiation COMSecurity

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

In my current project we have a COMInterface that we intialize in the beginning of the Code. It worked fine in VS2010 and VS2013 and we haven't made any changes. I can compile and run the code from VS2013 but the same code doesn't work in VS2017. I have tried 2 different machines.

The error given is

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
>
> HResult=0x80010119
>
> Message=Security must be initialized before any interfaces are marshalled or unmarshalled. It cannot be changed once initialized. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010119)
>
> Source=Cannot evaluate the exception source
>
> StackTrace: Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace

This is the first thing that happens in the application
App.xaml.cs

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitVS myApp;
        myApp = new InitVS();
    }
//More code
}


public class InitVS
{
    [DllImport("Ole32.dll",
        ExactSpelling = true,
        EntryPoint = "CoInitializeSecurity",
        CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall,
        SetLastError = false,
        PreserveSig = false)]

    private static extern void CoInitializeSecurity(
        IntPtr pVoid,
        int cAuthSvc,
        IntPtr asAuthSvc,
        IntPtr pReserved1,
        uint dwAuthnLevel,
        uint dwImpLevel,
        IntPtr pAuthList,
        uint dwCapabilities,
        IntPtr pReserved3);

    public InitVS()
    {
        //Error happens here
        CoInitializeSecurity(IntPtr.Zero,
            -1,
            IntPtr.Zero,
            IntPtr.Zero,
            (uint)RpcAuthnLevel.PktPrivacy,
            (uint)RpcImpLevel.Impersonate,
            IntPtr.Zero,
            (uint)EoAuthnCap.DynamicCloaking,
            IntPtr.Zero);
    }
}
```

What makes me most confused is that it works in VS2013 (haven't tried VS2015).
We use Visual Studio Professional 2017 and Visual Studio Professional 2013.

I haven't really found any relating information. There is a ton about DLL import ofc but can't find anything that VS2017 does anything strange, or VS2013 for that mather.

Comment: It sounds like the COM security model has been tightened up since you wrote the code 8 years ago.  "Security must be initialized..." have you tried doing what the error message suggests?

Comment: I would also suggest that you take a look at all those `IntPtr.Zero` parameters in your `CoInitializeSecurity` call, that's always a red flag in my book, especially as regards security models..

Comment: The function always failed before, you just never noticed because you don't check its return value.  The debugger's exception configuration dialog is very different in VS2017, redesigned and now under Debug > Windows > Exception Settings.  Be careful with the checkboxes, particular the "Managed Debugging Assistants" that can diagnose this kind of failure.

Comment: Thank you for your sugestions. I have checked the Input parameters and they seem according to specifications. IntPtr.Zero is becaus you can't pass null as a value through COM (or something as that). Important thing is IntPtr.Zero = null in this case.

Comment: Hans Passant, the App() is the first first thing that happens.
I moved the initialization into class App() it gives me the same error. I don't know how you can make it run even earlier. :)
Going to look more into the exception handling.